# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.jws.WebMethod.exclude()Z

Tags: java, web-services, configuration, wsdl, cxf

I have generated stubs and client from a wsdl file and when I am trying to run the java application using the client, the below error is thrown.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.jws.WebMethod.exclude()Z
```

Is there any jar file or configuration missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.jws.WebMethod.exclude()Z
```

I think you have wrong version of jar file in classpath.

Make sure the code syntax you have is compatible with the jars you have in classpath.

Comment: Thought so, any idea which jar might cause the issue?

Comment: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.jws.WebMethod these are all the jars with javax.jws.WeMethod class. You may need to check your environment to findout which jar it is.

Comment: does axis2-jaxws-api-1.2.jar has something to do with jaxws-api-2.2.jar ? ( i have the later one in my library)

Comment: Yeah, it could be. I would suggest download appropriate version and try.